# UPS API Change to Auth2.0

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-methods, ups

Our client told us

*On 5 June 2023 UPS began the sunset process for access key authentication in favour of the more secure OAuth 2.0 model for all APIs. This change impacts all API integrations and requires updates to your existing application interface. If your integration is managed by a 3rd party, please contact the provider. The migration guide linked below can help answer questions about the transition from access keys to OAuth 2.0*

We are currently using magento 2.3.5. Is there any solution available for magento 2.3.5?
I can see there is patch available for magento 2.4.4 onwards https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/ups-shipping-method-integration-migration-from-soap-to-restful-api

My question is has any one tried to create fix for magento 2.3 version of magento?